# How can a change python SUDS receive data timeout?

Tags: python, soap, timeout, suds

I am developing and sdk for a company and a requirement is that that users can change in the options of my sdk  the DEFAULT CONNECTION TIME OUT and the DATA RECEIVE TIMEOUT.

Im connecting to a SOAP services with suds-jurko, and I can change the CONNECTION TIME OUT but I dont know how to change the DATA RECEIVE TIMEOUT

How can i change the DATA RECEIVE TIMEOUT?

i call DATA RECEIVE TIME OUT to the time that the suds have to wait for the response.